# Using two different SVN repositories for the same project

Tags: svn

As a consultant I usually have access to client's svn repository in order to checkout, work on and eventually commit projects.

The optimal (is a client request) would be to commit only stable versions on client's svn and avoid intermediate (i.e. non buildable) commits but I also would like to keep trace of developing process and enjoy the benefit of a versioning system...

Then it would be great to do something like:

- checkout PROJ from client's svn
- use an internal svn for developing
- commit stable version on client's svn

I am able to accomplish this tasks using some script (wich automatically perform checkout, remove .svn stuff, commit and so on) but that's really far away from being a smooth process.

I tried to search for a solution but I didn't find anything useful yet.

Does anyone know an easy and productive way to do that?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Does the client mind if you use a development branch and then just merge code into the stable branch when you're ready? Surely that's half of what branches are *for*...

Comment: Yes, you are definetely right and I know that is what branches are for... unfortunately that is not so clear in client's mind...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best and easiest solution will be use another SCM on your side + bridge to SVN (Mercurial + HGSubversion, **not Git**)

But even with pure SVN you have at least two viable solutions: Vendor Branches and Shared UUID

**Vendor Branches**

- Read [Vendor Branches topic from SVN Book](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html) (mostly [Vendor Branches from Foreign Repositories](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.vendorbr.html#svn.advanced.vendorbr.foreign-repos) part) and related [Externals Definitions](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.externals.html) chapter
- Build *your* repository with links to customer's repository according to "Vendor Branches" recommendations
- Perform your every-day work in your private part of your repository
- Merge polished and finished work into Vendor Branch and commit result (one big mergeset) into customer's repository (you have to have RW permissions on client's side for it)
- *(from time to time)* Merge another persons commits from client repo into your private branch in your repo

**Shared UUID**

You can change (for existing WC) URL of related SVN-repository by clean, legal way (`svn help relocate`), which is used mainly infrastructure management, but  can be usable for you.

FROM and TO repositories for relocating are assumed the same repository, identity verified by checking UUID of repository, thus: for two different repositories (client's and you) you have to provide the same UUID.

It can be easily achieved by load|dump cycle (`svnadmin dump` client's repo /or only needed nodes of it/, `svnadmin load ... --force-uuid` into your empty repository) and after it your can perform any job in your repository. "Ready to publish" work will appear in client's repo if you:

- relocate your WC to client's repository
- update (semi-automatically - you can't avoid it and non-conflicting merges will appear in your WC without your intervention) with missed changes from client's side
- commit your (possibly long-time) changes in WC (it will be "Modified", contrary to client's repo) as one giant commit
- relocate WC back to your repository

**PS**: "Vendor Branches" is more safe way from my POV at the cost of possible problems with Subversion's merges (which are still *not so beautiful* as in the DVCS-world)

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry that my answer implies using another VCS, but this is quite easy to do with git-svn. Commit to git during development, squash your commits in a single “clean” commit, then `dcommit` it to the SVN server.

This may be overcomplicated for your purpose if you're not a git user, though.

Comment: Thanks, I'd prefer to use svn but I'll definetly take this solution into account if nothing else comes out